# Viewing hostnames in network

Tags: linux, networking, windows, vpn, hostname

Is there Linux command equal to `Net View` in Windows, that shows hostnames in your network?

I am in a VPN network and want to see computer names in my network.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with the program `nmap`. If you specify an address in CIDR notation, it will scan all IPs in that block.

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24
```

The flag `-sP` will bypass port scanning and just indicate whether the host is up based on ping.